# underscore.js flatten object structure with key-value pair array of children

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Given the following data structure:

```
var data = [{
    name: "Some Name",
    id: 1,
    children: [
        { name: "prop1", value: 1 },
        { name: "prop2", value: 2 },
        { name: "prop3", value: 3 }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Some Other Name",
    id: 2,
    children: [
        { name: "prop1", value: 4 },
        { name: "prop2", value: 5 },
        { name: "prop3", value: 6 }
    ]
}];
```

...where children is a dynamic list, I "flatten" this structure using a couple of `_.each` loops like so:

```
_.each(data, d => {
    _.each(d.children, c => {
        d[c.name] = c.value;
    })
});
```

...only to achieve a 2-dimensional data structure like:

```
[{
    name: "Some Name",
    id: 1,
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3
},
{
    name: "Some Other Name",
    id: 2,
    prop1: 4,
    prop2: 5,
    prop3: 6
}];
```

So I was hoping there might be a neat way to achieve this with [undercore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)?

JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/3m3dsv47/

Comment: N.B. no. of children is consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another solution i came up with:

```
_.each(data, d => {
    _.extend(d, _.object(_.map(d.children, c => {
        return [c.name, c.value];
    })));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Lu0hu/

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses UnderscoreJS. In contrast to your own solution, this does not modify the original data, but creates a copy of it. I wouldn't say that it is "much neater", however here it is :)

```
_.map(data, function(e){ 
    return _.defaults({name: e.name, id: e.id}, 
      _.reduce(e.children, function (acc, e) {
        acc[e.name] = e.value; return acc; 
      }, {})
    ); 
  });
```

If I apply this to your data I get

```
 [
   {"name":"Some Name","Prop1":1,"Prop2":2,"Prop3":3},
   {"name":"Some Other Name","Prop1":4,"Prop2":5,"Prop3":6}
 ]
```

You could also omit the `_.reduce`. While it may look a bit more elegant, due to iterating over all children twice (`_.pluck`), it is even less efficient than the first one.

```
_.map(data, function(e){
    return _.defaults({id: e.id, name: e.name}, 
      _.object(_.pluck(e.children, 'name'), _.pluck(e.children, 'value'))
    );
});
```